# Parsing TWO comma delimited fields

Tags: sql-server

Using MS SQL Studio, I need to parse two comma delimited fields that align to each other.  For example:

```
Name           Pet_Name            Type
Bob            Sally,Betty,Sue     Cat,Dog,Cat
Dick           Mary,Fido,Polly     Dog,Dog,Bird

Parsed to:
Name           Pet_Name            Type
Bob            Sally               Cat
Bob            Betty               Dog
Bob            Sue                 Cat
Dick           Mary                Dog
Dick           Fido                Dog
Dick           Polly               Bird
```

With all the pet names matching up to their respective type.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried anything? searching? anything at all?

Comment: Yes, I have searched.  Several times, several places.  Normal "SplitString" type functions won't work for multiple fields.  Do you have any thoughts?

Comment: On stackoverflow there are many questions on this topic. Try searching .

Comment: I beg to differ.  I HAVE searched extensively.  All the hits I'm able to find deal with ONE comma delimited field.  Please, enlighten me on what search criteria you are using to find the many answers that I am not able to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an input table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Input
(
    Name NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Pet_Names NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Types NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Input (Name, Pet_Names, Types)
VALUES
    (N'Bob', N'Sally,Betty,Sue', N'Cat,Dog,Cat'), 
    (N'Dick', N'Mary,Fido,Polly', N'Dog,Dog,Bird');
```

Create a user-defined table function which splits the Pet_Names and Types.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_Split
(
    @name NVARCHAR(25),
    @pet_names NVARCHAR(200),
    @types NVARCHAR(200)
)
RETURNS @ret TABLE
(
    Name NVARCHAR(25),
    Pet_Name NVARCHAR(25),
    Type NVARCHAR(25)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pet_names2 NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @types2 NVARCHAR(200);
    DECLARE @i INT;
    DECLARE @j INT;
    DECLARE @p NVARCHAR(25);
    DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(25);

    SET @pet_names2 = @pet_names;
    SET @types2 = @types;

    WHILE LEN(@pet_names2) > 0 AND LEN(@types2) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @i = CHARINDEX(N',', @pet_names2);
        SET @j = CHARINDEX(N',', @types2);

        IF @i > 0 AND @j > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @p = SUBSTRING(@pet_names2, 1, @i-1);
            SET @pet_names2 = SUBSTRING(@pet_names2, @i+1, LEN(@pet_names2)-@i);

            SET @t = SUBSTRING(@types2, 1, @j-1);
            SET @types2 = SUBSTRING(@types2, @j+1, LEN(@types2)-@j);
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @p = @pet_names2;
            SET @pet_names2 = NULL;

            SET @t = @types2;
            SET @types2 = NULL;
        END

            INSERT INTO @ret (Name, Pet_Name, Type)
                VALUES(@Name, @p, @t);
    END

    RETURN
END;
```

Run a select statement.

```
SELECT T.*
    FROM dbo.Input AS I
        CROSS APPLY dbo.ufn_Split(I.Name, I.Pet_Names, I.Types) AS T;
```

Results

```
Name        Pet_Name    Type
Bob         Sally       Cat
Bob         Betty       Dog
Bob         Sue         Cat
Dick        Mary        Dog
Dick        Fido        Dog
Dick        Polly       Bird
```

Code written in T-SQL and tested on SQL Server 2012.

Caveat this is demo code and not robust enough for a production system. You'd have to consider error cases like different number of items in Pet_Names and Types.

Comment: If the data volumes are high, SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) would give a better solution.

Comment: This mostly works for me.  The issue is that per name, once it got a Type length of 3, it keeps 3 until the final record.  This isn't an issue in the above example, but if the input were Cat,Bird,Bird,Dog: It gives me "Cat" "Bir" ",Bi" "d,dog"

Comment: You'd need to post your code so we can see what is going on. Don't forget to mark my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: The only difference is the order of pet types. To replicate, use your code, but use this slightly different table declaration:
CREATE TABLE dbo.Input
(
    Name NVARCHAR(25) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Pet_Names NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    Types NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Input (Name, Pet_Names, Types)
VALUES
    (N'Bob', N'Sally,Betty,Sue', N'Bird,Dog,Cat'), 
    (N'Dick', N'Mary,Fido,Polly', N'Dog,Bird,Bird');

Comment: Ah! There was a little buglet in my code. I've code stepped the function in SSMS. In several places in the function, I was using the variable (at)types instead of (at)types2. I've amended the answer above. Hope that fixes it for you!

Comment: That does it!  Thanks!